# Can a Facebook plugin leak profile information?

Tags: facebook, tracking, profile

I had a discussion with a friend today and he claimed that by using some [Facebook Social Plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) on your site, you could find out Facebook profile information about the visitor of your website (if he or she is logged in to facebook).

I claimed there is no way that's possible in javascript, beceause of the "same origin policy". I am right? Or maybe there's a  way using ajax, flash or canvas?

If possible I think people should be aware of it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugins operate by creating an iframe, so there is no way for your website to get this information via javascript. The only way to get information about the logged-in facebook user is if the user authorizes your application.